# How to search for specific text in other text and retrive information

Tags: r

This is the first time I post here and I appreciate your help.
I have two different large text files:
First# a.txt has one column like:

```
rs151511
rs4156465
rs15651
chr1:1545455
```

Second one b.txt has three columns with large number of rows:

```
rs151511    45615614  1
rs4156465   51156155  2
rs15651     15615615  3
rs151655    45615614  1
rs156161    51156155  2
rs122242    15615615  3
```

I need to write a code which produces a new file "c.txt" which has file#1 list with identical information from file#2 with the below format:

```
rs151511       45615614  1
rs4156465      51156155  2
rs15651        15615615  3
chr1:1545455   1545455   1
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are both dataframes or matrices in R, the following should work.

```
final <- b[which(b[, 1] %in% a[, 1]), ]
write.table(final, "c:/c.txt", sep="\t")
```

If you have a vector, you should be able to switch the a[, 1] with the vector a. There is a [readlines](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html) function for reading in difficult txt files that you may want to look at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just have the last line in a.txt which is chr1:1545455.  I want to add it to c.txt as chr1:1545455 ch1 1545455. I do not know how to split ch1 from number and add it to the file. I appreciate your help

Comment: If it is only that line and only once:

Comment: rbind(final, c('chr1:1545455', 1545455, 1)

Comment: Excuse me: Whey there is " within the file elements? such as "V1" "V2" "V3"
"7160" "chr1" 785910 "rs12565286"
"10570" "chr1" 849670 "rs2905062"
"42158" "chr1" 1205055 "rs1815606"
"92869" "chr1" 1774697 "rs6603811"

Comment: Dear Sam, I have millions of them, How to do it automatically? Thank you very much

Comment: It is the same question here:
I have the  below file:
chr1:109457160 
chr1:109457233 
chr1:109457614 
I need to get new one like:
chr1:109457160       chr1        109457160
chr1:109457233  chr1        109457233 
chr1:109457614  chr1        109457614 

How to do it in R?

I appreciate your reply

Comment: Look at using grepl('chr1', a[, 1]). I don't quite understand what you want to do with those.